# xCode draw - Trying to maintain color choice in CGRect

Tags: xcode, core-graphics, cgrect

I have a simple drawing class. There is a view controller that includes a color selection bar. Then a UIView that has the CGRect draw functions.

I can draw ok, but when I change the color, all existing strokes are changed. What have I messed up? I want to only change colors for new strokes.

Any help would be welcome. Here are some relevant code snippets:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [currentColor setStroke]; 

        for (UIBezierPath *_path in pathArray) 
    [_path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];  
}

#pragma mark - Touch Methods
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    swiped = NO;

    myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    myPath.lineWidth=10;
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    [myPath moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    [pathArray addObject:myPath];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        [self eraseButtonClicked];
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;


}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    swiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    [myPath addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 15.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    moved++;    
    if (moved == 10) {
        moved = 0;
    }

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        [self eraseButtonClicked];
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawRect: is drawing all the paths in the same colour. When you call [currentColor setStroke], you are setting the colour for all the strokes you draw. You'll need to maintain the colours for the strokes as well, and reset the colour before each call to strokeWithBlendMode.

Something like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    for( int i=0; i<[pathArray count]; i++) {
        [[colorArray objectAtIndex:i] setStroke];
        [[pathArray objectAtIndex:i] strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

You'll have to make sure you add a UIColor object to the colorArray every time you add a path to pathArray.

You could add `[colorArray addObject:currentColor];` after the line `[pathArray addObject:myPath];`

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for answering. Perhaps I don't understand completely.. I have a segmented control of seven colors. Are you saying that I should make an array of those? What happens when the user taps a specific button.. Could you please elaborate. Thanks for answering.. David

Comment: I'm assuming you are changing the currentColor variable when the user taps the colour control. That will work, but you need to keep track of what colour the user has selected when you add the new path to the pathArray. That's why I suggest adding the currentColor to a new array that will match up with the pathArray.

Comment: Also, if you remove a path from the pathArray, you'll need to remove the corresponding colour from the colorArray as well or they won't be synchronized.

Comment: Oh, I understand, I need a compound array if I need to keep track of both lines and colors... Thanks for the explanation. Are there any other ways of implementing this kind of action?

Comment: I would probably create an array of custom objects representing the coloured paths, and have each object store the path and the colour.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, that's different from your code example above right? If you could provide a code snippet,  I will be most grateful.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I created a sample project on github to demonstrate what I mean. Take a look at https://github.com/martica/TouchDraw.

OMMTouchableView is the UIView subclass, and OMMColouredPath is an NSObject subclass that holds the path and the colour. I went a little farther with the idea and pushed the drawing into OMMColouredPath, and hooked up the undo and erase with the new layout.

Comment: That's perfect Tyler. I don't know how to thank you enough.. Just wish me luck, my daughter is having a baby in the morning.. The code sample is perfect, and I'm really appreciative.. David

Comment: Tyler, sorry to bother you once more.. Everything is fine, but how could I add a redo function?  Many thanks again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10126/discussion-between-tyler-bindon-and-david-delmonte)